# Simple linear regression

Tags: regression, self-study, linear-model, consistency, identifiability

Consider the simple regression model $y=\beta_0+\beta_1x+u$, where $\text{corr}(x,u)=1$ and all random variables have normal distributions. Is it possible to provide asymptotically consistent estimates for $\beta_1$?

Since $corr(x,u)=1$, we can write  $u=ax+b$ and substitute it to get $y=\beta_0+b+(\beta_1+a)x$. So our observations lie on the straight line given by this equation. What sort of conclusion can we derive from this?

Comment: It would be nice to know how did you arrive at this question. I cannot imagine real life situation where such type of information about regression model would be available. (For that matter no imaginary life situation is possible too)

Comment: I am preparing for exam, so this is one from the last year's final.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*This is a weird question:* the simple regression model is defined conditional to the regressor $X$, hence (a) for each observation $y_1$, $x_i$ is observed as well and (b) if the noise $U$ is perfectly correlated with $X$, this means that the noise $u_i$ is also observed: $u_i=ax_i+b$.

**Conclusion:** there is no randomness and one only needs two observations to derive *w/o error* the parameters $(\beta_0+b,\beta_1+a)$, therefore $(\beta_0,\beta_1)$ if $(a,b)$ is known.

**Note:** If $(a,b)$ is unknown, w/o any additional assumption, all one can estimate is $(\beta_0+b,\beta_1+a)$.

Comment: And how to show rigorously, that if we don't know the coefficients in the linear relation $u=ax+b$, then we can not estimate $\beta_1$ consistently? (That is, we only know the fact that $corr(x,u)=1$)

Comment: @marcin63:  all your observations $(x_i,y_i)$ will be on the same line with parameters $(\beta_0+b,\beta_1+a)$. So you can only estimate the slope and intercept of this line.

Comment: Yes, i understand that we can only estimate $\beta_1+a$, so we are not able to recover estimate of $\beta_1$ from this model. But probably it can be shown more explicitly that we have an identification problem and can not suggest estimate of $\beta_1$?

Comment: @marcin63: the identifiability problem is explained in my previous answer. All you get is $\beta_0+b$, exactly. The proof of non-identifiability cannot be more explicit than that.

Answer (score 6):

This is not simple linear regression. Simple linear regression is $y = \beta_0 + \beta_1x + u$, but with cor(x, u) = 0. Indeed, your second equation $y = \beta_0 + b + (\beta_1 + a)x$ is the simple linear regression for the situation, but you should add $u$ with $u \sim \mathcal{N}(0,0)$

One can conclude that this is fantasy land, because all the observations *never* lie exactly on the line. George Box said "all models are wrong but some models are useful". You've posited a model which is exactly right. No model error, no measurement error.